# If $x_{2n}$, $x_{2n+1}$, and $x_{3n}$ are Cauchy sequences, then so is $x_n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that the sequences
\begin{align}
y_n = x_{2n}, \quad z_n = x_{2n+1}, \quad w_n = x_{3n}
\end{align}
are Cauchy sequences. I need to prove that $(x_n)_n$ is also Cauchy.

How can I prove this?

My trial: Let $p\in \mathbb{N}$, $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. I want to show that
\begin{align}
|x_{n+p} - x_n| < \varepsilon
\end{align}
for sufficiently large $n$. If $n$ is even, I considered the cases where $p$ is even and $p$ is odd. If $p$ is even, we are done as $(y_n)_n$ is Cauchy. But I could not proceed if $p$ is odd.

Is there any alternative approach?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider $6k$ and $6l+3.$

Comment: May you clarify please? @RyszardSzwarc

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1250672/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/138987/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/549654/42969

Comment: For large $k$ and $l$ the terms $x_{6k}$ and $x_{6l+3}$ are close to each other. Besides $x_{6k}$ and $x_{2n}$ are close for large $n,$ , $x_{2m+1}$ and $x_{6l+3}$ are close. Therefore $x_{2n}$ is close to $x_{2m+1}.$